# Python replace text in string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using a software that can handle python scripts. There are list/tables in it, like layers. I can get the list, but cannot replace part of the text.

list:

```
06H_906_283_B__DMU_TMU_000_000_EL-UMSCHALTVENTIL_______________________S_P@SKIN
05E_906_051____GEO_TM__001_____DRUCKSENSOR________09_08_2016_EE_______.1\NAUO7\
03H_260_089_K__DMU_TMU_000_000_HALTER__________________________________S_POS001
ENT_406_001_FB_GEO_TM__009_____HALTER_SENSOR_MOT__________20170502_VIF.1\PartBo
```

want to replace stuff like:

```
TM_009 to TM009
_GEO_  to 'delete'
______ to _
```

Tried many things, but nothing worked.
I think easiest way would be a dictionary.
But I'm stuck and can't get it to work.

some part that I have yet:
...

```
names = base.GetEntityCardValues(deck, prop, ('Name',))   #getting the list with names
    for prop in props:
        dict = {
        'EN_0+':'EN0',
        '-TM_0':'-TM0',
        '_+':'_',
        'DMU_':'',
        'GEO_':'',
        }
```

.
.
.stuck with the replacing
.
.
base.SetEntityCardValues(deck, prop, {'Name':new_names}) #the end where I want to write back the new names

Comment: regex will probably be easiest.

Comment: tried that too, but I'm a noob and couldn't work it out

Comment: What is `-` suppose to mean? I figure `+` means _more than one_.

Comment: - is just a hyphen

Comment: show us what have you worked out through regular expressions. It seems the obvious way to do it, IMHO, but you should work them a little bit. If you are not used to build regular expressions, there are interactive websites (like [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/)) where you can try your regular expressions and learn how to build them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried [str.replace()](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)?

```
str = str.replace("TM_009", "TM009")
```

or for multiple replacements:

```
string = "TM_009 abc A"
print(string)

repl = {"TM_009": "TM009", "A": "B"}
for orig,repl in repl.items():
   string = string.replace(orig, repl)

print(string)
```

Output:

> TM_009 abc A
>
> TM009 abc B

Is this what you need?

Comment: Doesn't answer the OP's question completely. For example inputs like `______ to _`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work. Has a glitch with the mentioned part (_____), but for start its great. thanks